# Running CI/CD pipelines in AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, command-line-interface

As a project, I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline running inside an AWS Lambda application.

The problem I am facing is that AWS Lambda is missing some tools (for example `xargs`) that certain applications (for example Gradle) require to run properly:

`/tmp/repo/gradlew: line 234: xargs: command not found`

Or even more interestingly:

`install: apt-get: command not found`

How can I install the required tools to build the applications from within an AWS Lambda container?

How can I utilize layers to speed up those containers?
Aka, I assume I need to register that certain cli tools are present in mounted layers.
On windows, I would do this by (ab)using the PATH environment variable, but what is the recommended way to do this in Linux?

And how can I tell tools to look for their dependencies in those layers? to avoid errors like:
`ld.gold: error: cannot find -lcurl`

Answer (score 1):

The best option as far as I can tell is to create a Docker image containing all the software that you require and provide this to the AWS Lambda service.

There is extensive documentation how to run Docker containers in AWS Lambda:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

---

**Personal note**: While I like the idea of a challenge or proof-of-concept I'd recommend using one of the many CI/CD services out there instead of building one on your own. I can not think of any upside of this. AWS itself offers CI/CD solutions like AWS CodePipeline etc.

You might want to have a look at the following documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/set-up-ci-cd-pipeline/

Comment: I will try to use docker and see if I have more success with that.

Comment: The reason I do all of this is to avoid the tedious setups that all the CI/CD tools have. I don't want to define the build in a yaml file because they are very difficult to get right and really hard to debug or expand and in many cases reuse properly. I also don't want to build a new pipeline for every repository because this would scale extremely bad for my thousand repositories that almost all would have the same pipeline. I also wanted to avoid EC2 or Fargate because I am very comfortable with how Lambda works and a lot of tools I use work best with Lambda.

Comment: I also tried some CI/CD services. The last one was circleci, but on that one, there were missing dependencies and once I stalled them, the gradle build just closes unexpectedly. Which also is not fun to debug let alone fix.

Comment: @Wietlol No need to explain yourself. You have your reasons. A few more things to consider: Lambdas run for a maximum of 900 seconds (15 minutes). I have a couple Java projects that need longer to build than 15 minutes, so keep that in mind. Furthermore, Lambdas scale vCPU by memory. More memory, more CPU. 1-6 cores. If you want to have fast builds you need a lot of memory. This will become costly. Also remember that you probably need to attach EFS volume because the 512MB disk of the Lambda are not enough for `.m2/repository`.

Comment: for pricing, I know that the lambda pricing is about a millionth of a dollar per megabyte minute, so for a 10G (max) lambda container, I'd be paying 1 cent per build minute.
if I end up needing an EFS, that'd also mean I'd need to run it from within a VPC and thus needing a network gateway, which is probably a few orders of magnitude more expensive than the lambda cost

Comment: currently, I am just trying to get a build running from within docker on my local machine, but I receive a "tar exit code 2" when gradle is unpacking dependencies (after which I just took a break). after I have it running, I'd probably have the docker image contain most common libraries, to speed up the build process, which would solve the 512MB limit of the /tmp/ folder by insalling the dependencies anywhere I'd like (I think when using a docker image, you can ship it with more files in other locations than /tmp)

Comment: as for the problem of `apt-get`, the linux2 machines apparently run fine with `yum` for installs. and the xargs problem appears to be solved in the docker container